# How to make an output file specific to each variable in while read line loop? Nikto ZSH

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, zsh

In Zsh, I want to run a Nikto scan on a list of URLs and have the output be:

`($line)-nikto-results.html`

I have so far :

```bash
while IFS= read -r line;
do nikto -h $line -o $line-nikto-results.html -F html;
done <list-Of-IPs-or-URLs.txt
```

When I run it, only one line is scanned and one file created.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t use `read`, but do it like this:

```bash
local text="$( 
    < list-Of-IPs-or-URLs.txt 
)"
local -a lines=(
    "${(f@)text}" 
)
local url=
for url in lines; do
  nikto -h "$url" -o ${url}-nikto-results.html -F html
done
```